# open notepad ++ with a batch file and get it to return the prompt after running it

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off 
rem bath file name: NNP.bat 
rem created by: mark g
rem this batch file while open notepad++ 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %1
```

this is the batch file i have to open notepad ++ from the command line but it wont return the prompt after i run it until i close out the notepad++ program i know theres a way to get it to return while the program is still open.

```
what i want it to do is open a file in notepad++ and be able to run more commands 
 the way its written now it will open the program but waits for the program to close to return the prompt
```

Comment: `Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"`, should do it.

Comment: okay thank you for that but i tried the start command before and it opened a command prompt window so what does the two double quotes mean just so i understand why it works with the quotes but not with out them ?

Comment: Opening a Command Prompt window and enter `start /?`, will provide you with the usage and options for the command. `""` is an empty title, _(as the first doublequoted argument is seen as the title)_. This prevents you starting a window titled `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe`. So, before rubbishing my knowledge on the subject, try it please!

Comment: I am not rubbishing your knowledge of the subject i just wanted to know how it worked exactly because i tried it before just not with the double quotes so i wanted to know what the double quotes meant . i was not trying to make it seem like it was a worthless answer it actually helped me understand it more so thank you again sorry for any confuision have a good day @Compo

Comment: Marky2019, have you now tried it? and can you confirm that it works exactly as intended?

Comment: Yes it does work as intended thank you very much for the answer and the knowledge on the subject